# Analogue to appending "s" to the end of an acronym when plural does not have an "s"

Tags: acronyms, irregular-plurals

Some acronyms can be naturally pluralized. For example, consider the acronym RTP which stands for regional tax policy -- the plural is regional tax policies and thus the acronym can be written as RTPs.

What about for words whose plural does not use an "s"? For example, consider the acronym NE which stands for Nash equilibrium -- the plural is Nash equilibria, so writing NEs doesn't make any sense. Should one accept the ambiguity and write NE for both Nash equilibrium and Nash equilibria?

Comment: You should consider the abbreviation as a separate thing from the expansion.  Just as you would say "**an** RTP" in place of "**a** Regional Tax Policy", you can (and should) say "some NEs" in place of "some Nash Equilibria".  (I don't have a source or authority for this so I'm not making it an answer, just a comment.)

Comment: NEs indeed makes sense, We have for example MEPs for Members of the European Parliament, and POTUSes for Presidents of the United States. Also in a mathematical context, cellular automata are often called CAs. The full form's plural has no bearing on the abbreviation's plural.

Comment: *RTP* is not an acronym.

Comment: @jsw29 https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acronym